# Export MFC DLL application object

Tags: c++, visual-c++, dll, mfc, dllexport

In developing MFC DLLs, there is a common feature of a DLL application object.  This is generated by the MFC DLL template as something like the following:

```
// The one and only DllApp object
DllApp theApp;
```

where `DllApp` extends `CWinApp` and serves as a way of managing DLL-generic data storage and operations.

Typically this object is private to the DLL, but there are some cases in which I require its functionality in the API.  Asking as one only barely aware of how AFX module state etc. works, is it valid to export `theApp`, or would it be better to write and export a facade class, or simple wrapper functions?  Put another way, is there a reason `theApp` should remain strictly internal?

Comment: You pretty much answered your question already: The `DllApp` accesses module-private state. For that to work reliably, you have to switch to the module state at the module boundary, since the module's implementation uses the current state. Exposing the `DllApp` to foreign code will inevitably lead to it using foreign state. The chaos that ensues is pretty challenging to debug.

Comment: @IInspectable, thanks for the traffic.  That makes sense.  If you wouldn't mind please post this as an answer, and include a suggested alternative - e.g. do you think a wrapper layer of sorts would be a reasonable way to mediate the data across the module boundary?

Comment: I'll see what I can do, once I'm back at a real keyboard, and a screen larger than my palm. It would probably make for an even better Q&A if you quickly explained, why you need external code to access internal state. This information will be helpful in producing viable alternatives.

Comment: I have logic I wish to expose to a C++ style API, which performs operations on DLL-generic data.  I have this implemented as methods of the `DllApp` class.  If I were to write a wrapper layer, a set of wrapper functions or a facade class would be able to set the module state, access the `DllApp` object, and call the wrapped methods.  I would probably prefer to make it a facade class with a set of static methods, if only to make it more C++esque/OOP.